# Nhibernate Filter in a Join table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hbm

I'll try to filter to have a one to one join in subclasses,

I set the filter condition in key column field, in a simple query it works, in more complicated it does not resolve alias.

is there a trick for setting the alias in the second column??

```
<join table="Aview" inverse="true">
      **<key column="ID_A and ID_C=:MyFilter.IdCC" />**
      <property name="IdBlabla" insert ="false" update ="false" column="ID_BlaBla"/>
      <property name="Tipo" insert ="false" update ="false" />
      <many-to-one name="CC" column="ID_C" cascade="none" insert ="false" update ="false"/>
    </join>
```